# Android - Loading, please wait

Tags: android, multithreading

Is there a standard "Loading, please wait" dialog I can use in Android development, when I invoke some AsyncTask (downloading some data from remote service for example)?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You mean something like an indeterminate [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)?

Edit: i.e.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
```

then call `dialog.dismiss()` when done.

Comment: FYI, This class was deprecated in API level 26.  Suggested alternatives are https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.

Answer (score 19):

If you implement runnable as well as extending Activity then you could handle the code like this...

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public void downloadData() {
    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Downloading Data..", "Please wait", true,false);
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
// add downloading code here
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
 }

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pDialog().dismiss();
        // handle the result here
    }
};
```

It's worth mentioning that you can set the content view of the progress dialog so you can display a custom message / image:)

```
pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.X);
```

Answer (score 10):

Mirko is basically correct, however there are two things to note:

1. `ProgressDialog.show()` is a shortcut that automatically creates a dialog.  Unlike other dialogs, it should NOT be used in `onCreateDialog()`, as it will cause errors in Android 1.5.
2. There are some further issues with AsyncTask + ProgressDialog + screen orientation changes that you should be aware of - [check this out](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bf046b95cf38832d/?pli=1).

Comment: thanks for list of things to watch out! 

and by the way, cute Braid icon you have there :)