# what to use instead of black screen

Tags: android

I have 3 activities in my Android app. The first is the main menu where I press the button which opens an ssh connection and on my raspberry pi it does different kind of things (downloading uploading etc). This process generally takes 15-20 seconds and when it is ready, the third activity comes up where i can see the files that my rpi made.

The problem is, that during the above mentioned 15-20 seconds the user can see nothing but only the black screen.

Which is better and easier? Warn the user that the file he/she requests will get dowloaded soon and run the process int the background or make a little moving loading sign so the user has to wait till the end of the process. Can anyone tell me how to do it/them?

Thanks

Comment: This might be useful: [Android - Loading, please wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981156/android-loading-please-wait)

Comment: use progress dialog box to show the downloading process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your blocking calls in an AsyncTask or a thread (AsyncTask is preferred). Whilst it is running, show a ProgressBar set to indeterminate. Below that bar I'd show some text informing about the delay.
AsyncTasks are pretty easy and you can start in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `rxjava`

```
    notifyTheUserThatTheProcessWasStarted();
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> doALongOperation())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(() -> notifyTheUserThatTheProcessHasEnded());
```

The above code is just an example to see what it might look like, and will probably need to be adapted to your problem. `rxjava` is more difficult to learn than `AsyncTask`, but it will allow you to create more complex async logic

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava